# Help me to create regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Format date: `MMM D[,] YYYY`

`[,]` - optional comma and may be some space . Example:

```
Nov 12,     2000 - true
Nov 12 2000 - true
Nov 12, 2000 - true
Nov      12,    2000 true
```

My regExp:`/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\ *(\d{1,2})\,? *(\d{4})$/`
But if value - March 2010 all if true

My function for check value

```
function checkDateWithStringMonth1(value) {
        //reset
        resetDate();
        //set min and max date
        var minYear = 1900;
        //var maxYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        // regular expression to match required date format
        re = /^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\ *(\d{1,2})\,? *(\d{4})$/;
        //check correct
        if (value != '') {
            if (regs = value.match(re)) {
               if (regs[2] < 1 || regs[2] > 31) {
                    return false;
                }
                if(regs[3] < minYear){return false;}
            } else { return false; }
        } else { return false; }
        //assign

        return true;        
    }
```

Comment: I'm not a JS expert but isn't there a function that can convert date strings to date objects?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Are you saying giving this the string 'March 2010' returns `true`?

Comment: Is `Mar 12,2010` valid? (no space after comma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d{1,2}),?\s+(\d{4})$/
```

Differences from your original:

- `\s` instead of [space] to handle different kinds of whitespace
- `+` instead of `*`: `*` means 0 or more, you want 1 or more
- No need to escape `,`.

Edit: To accomodate dates with no space after the comma:

```
/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d{1,2})(?:,|\s)\s*(\d{4})$/
```

- `(?:` stats a non-capturing group.
- `(?:,|\s)\s*`: Allow for a comma or a whitespace character, and then possibly more whitespace.

Test:

```
var dates = ["Nov 12,     2000", "Nov 12 2000", "Nov 12, 2000", "Nov      12,    2000", "Nov 12,2000"],
    regex = /^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d{1,2})(?:,|\s)\s*(\d{4})$/;

dates.map(function (d) { return regex.test(d); });
// => [true, true, true, true, true]
```

Comment: but Mar 12,2010 valid. need change.

Comment: necessarily must be one divider

Comment: The second regex is valid for all your examples.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you do NOT need to escape commas. This might help.
and instead of using spaces, you might want to use the space character `\s` which will detect spaces, new lines and tabs (the new lines might not apply to you though).

Comment: what symbol say that one or more? * - zero or more; ? - zero or one; what symbol say one or more?

Comment: the `+` character will match one or more of the previous character(s)